# Why does my clickable image not work?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I am trying to make a version of cookie clicker to practice making games but the important part doesn't work: When you click the cookie, nothing happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script language="javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cookie" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130827014912/cookieclicker/images/thumb/5/5a/PerfectCookie.png/250px-PerfectCookie.png"></div>
    <div>
    <script language="javascript">
        //variables:
        var cookieClicks = 0;
        var cookieClicked;
        //code:
        var cookie = document.getElementById("cookie").onclick = cookieClicked(){
            return true;
        };         // gets the element

        //checks if cookie is clicked + add cookie
        if(cookieClicked === true){
            cookieClicks ++;
        }
        document.write(cookieClicks + " Cookies");
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should happen exactly ?

Comment: The only thing that should happen according to that code when you click a cookie is `return true`. Which is not an awful lot. The `if(cookieClicked)` part is ran way before the cookie can be clicked. Also you can't use "return" to get a value from a click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're currently doing is not the correct way to handle div click event. Assuming you want to increment `cookieClicks` and display the value of `cookieClicks` followed by `" Cookies"` each time the div is clicked, change your script to below

```
<script language="javascript">

    //variables:
    var cookieClicks = 0;

    function cookieClicked() {
        cookieClicks++;
        alert(cookieClicks + " Cookies");
    }
</script>
```

and add `onclick="cookieClicked();"` to the `cookie` div

```
<div id="cookie" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="cookieClicked();"><img     src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130827014912/cookieclicker/images/thumb/5/5a/PerfectCookie.png/250px-PerfectCookie.png"></div>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p87zks60/

Answer (score 0):

The code inside `onclick` event handler (`cookieClicked`) executes whenever user click on the image. So you should do the job in the event handler, moreover you should use `function` before the name of event handler, this name is optional if you use `function`

```
var cookieClicks = 0;    
var cookie = document.getElementById("cookie").onclick = function cookieClicked()
{
       cookieClicks ++;
 };         // gets the element
```

Answer (score 0):

may be try this:

```js
 
    
    var cookieClicks = 0;
    
    function cookieClicked() {
       
       document.getElementById("count").innerHTML= ++cookieClicks + " Cookies";
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script language="javascript">
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cookie" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="cookieClicked()"><img     src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130827014912/cookieclicker/images/thumb/5/5a/PerfectCookie.png/250px-PerfectCookie.png"></div>
    <div>
    <p id="count"></p>
   
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```